# Map method not rerendering following state change?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am making an app in react native.  When a touchable highlight is pressed, the method submitOrder is called.  I cannot see a reason as to why the submitOrder method is not updating the state of the pendingOrdeers. Because of that, I believe the map method is the issue in my code.  I also believe the map method is the issue as I have tested removing all items from the array, and the map method still does not rerender.  Any relevant code is as follows:

```
const [dropdownSelected, setDropSelected] = React.useState('');
const [foodSelected, setFoodSelected] = React.useState('');
pendingOrders = [
    { time: '10:00 AM', orderLocation: data[0].value, orderItems: 'Joe' },
  ];

submitOrder = () => {
    pendingOrders.splice(pendingOrders.length, 0, {
      time: "selected.timePickup",
      orderLocation: "dropdownSelected",
      orderItems: "foodSelected"
    });
  };

<View style={styles.pendingOrdersBox}>
  {pendingOrders.map((order) => (
    <View style={styles.orderBoxArrange}>
      <Text style={styles.smallBoldText}>{order.time}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.smallBoldText}>
        {order.orderLocation}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.smallBoldText}>{order.orderItems}</Text>
     </View>
    ))},
</View>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => submitOrder()}>
                <View style={styles.submitButton}>
                  <Text style={styles.smallBoldText}>dad</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
```

If any extra code is needed, please let me know and I would be happy to provide it.

I tried multiple different methods to update the array, including splice, push, and concat.  I also tested to make sure it was the map method that is the issue.

Comment: can you please show the code for submitOrder function, I want to see how are you updating the state?

Comment: map method does not re-render. It is not the state.

Comment: if pending order is not a state and it's  just a variable then state won't update.

Comment: I just added the submitOrder function.  Sorry for forgetting to include it originally.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the `pendingOrders` state in your code.

You need to use either `useState` or `setState` to do it :

Then you can update the state in `submitOrders` method by calling `setPendingOrders`

```js
const [pendingOrders, setPendingOrders] = useState([  { time: '10:00 AM', orderLocation: data[0].value, orderItems: 'Joe' },
]);

const submitOrder = () => {
  const newOrder = { time: '11:00 AM', orderLocation: dropdownSelected, orderItems: foodSelected };
  setPendingOrders([...pendingOrders, newOrder]);
};
```

```js
<View style={styles.pendingOrdersBox}>
  {pendingOrders.map((order) => (
    <View style={styles.orderBoxArrange}>
      <Text style={styles.smallBoldText}>{order.time}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.smallBoldText}>
        {order.orderLocation}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.smallBoldText}>{order.orderItems}</Text>
     </View>
    ))}
</View>
```